# Why is the variable modified when nginx Lua processes the request?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I just started studying Lua.

Every time I request, I want to check the name parameter in the request parameter. However, it is actually found that the self.name has changed occasionally.

For example,

```
request A with params: request_id = 123 & name = ABC, 
request B with params: request_id = 321 & name = EFG,
```

in the log, I found that there are `requests_id = 123`, but `name = EFG`.

Why is that? Is my class incorrectly written?

---

Here is the sample code：

main.lua:

```
local checker = require "checker"
local ch = checker:new()

    
if ch:check_name() then
    ngx.header["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

checker.lua:

```
local utils = require "utils"


local _M = {}


function _M:new()
    local o = {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self

    self.args = utils.get_req_args() or {}

    local name = self.args["name"] or ""
    local request_id = self.args["request_id"] or ""

    self.name = name
    return o
end

function _M:check_name()
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "request_id: ", self.request_id, " name: ", self.name)
    
    -- do some check ...
end
```

utils.lua

```
local json = require "cjson"

local _M = {}

function _M.new(self)
    return self
end


function _M.get_req_args()
    -- GET 
    local args = nil
    if ngx.var.request_method == "GET" then
        args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
    -- POST 
    elseif ngx.var.request_method == "POST" then
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        args = json.decode(data)
    end
    return args
end
```

Comment: In checker.lua, in constructor (`_M:new`), `self` is the “class” object (that is, the `_M` table). You should set `o`'s attributes (`name`, `args`, etc.), not `self`'s ones. `o` is the newly created instance.

Comment: It seems to be caused by the reason you mentioned. I have fixed it, and it is under observation. Thank you very much for your help.